# Velocity and acceleration measurement in a video

Tags: opencv, processing, velocity, frames, units-of-measurement

I am trying to find a method to calculate the velocity and acceleration of a tracked object, lets say a ball falling. I am using Processing 2 to make this program, and I know the distance from the camera to the object and it can calculate its position in every frame during the motion.

To calculate the velocity, I used this formula (all calculated in pixels): VelocityX=(PositionX - LastPositionX)/delta time

And something similar with acceleration: AccelerationX=(VelocityX - LastVelocityX)/delta time

Then, I changed delta time with frames. So now I have velocity and acceleration in Pixels per frame, but my question is how can I transform this Pixels per frame unit to mm/s for example? to more intuitive units like that.

I calculate the position in  pixels too, but I make a conversion to mm after that, but I'm a little confused about how to do that for velocity and acceleration.

```cpp
// Get the current time
currTime = frameCount;
deltaTime = (currTime - prevTime);

// Remember current time for the next frame
prevTime = currTime;

// Calculate velocity in X and Y directions (pixels / frame)
if (lastMovingX != Float.MAX_VALUE) {
    velX = (PX - lastMovingX) / deltaTime;
    velY = (PY - lastMovingY) / deltaTime;
}

// Save the current frame position for the next calculation
lastMovingX = PX;
lastMovingY = PY;
if (lastVelX != Float.MAX_VALUE) {
    accelX = (velX - lastVelX) / deltaTime;
    accelY = (velY - lastVelY) / deltaTime;
}

lastVelX = velX;
lastVelY = velY;
```

Comment: There isn't a standard way to do this, as it's going to depend entirely on what screen the user is displaying on. 100 pixels on a phone vs 100 pixels on a projector are going to be very different measurements in millimeters. Why do you think you need to convert to millimeters?

Comment: The measurement in this units are necessary for my project, so the user understands the results in more familiar units. What do you suggest to do to accomplish this? my screen is 640x480 pixels. And I introduce the distance from the camera to the object.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. You want to track the object in millimeters, not something you're drawing on a screen. That's more a question for computer vision than it is for Processing specifically. It also probably depends on the type of camera you're using (a fish-eye lens versus a telephoto lens will give you very different results, for example). You might have better luck posting on a computer vision forum.

Comment: All the part about computer vision is done, the only thing I am missing is how to transform this pixels per frame unit to mm/s . I am using a 30fps webcam.

Comment: Converting from pixels to real-world units is a computer vision problem. It's going to depend on the type of lens you use, as well. It's hard to find that type of specialized expertise on StackOverflow, which is why you might want to look for a computer vision forum. Just make sure to link between crossposts if you do. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the size of the object, you can extract the ratio of pixels/mm. If you know your frame rate, you can convert frames to seconds.

To find pixels/mm = Object size in pixels / object size in mm

(pixels/frame) / (pixels/mm) = mm/frame

mm/frame * frames/second  = mm / second

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes! I was looking for this, I was a little confused about the approach I should take, thanks for clarify. I will test the results with this and then let you know if it worked.